# Fade effect at top and bottom of NSTableView/NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, fade, nsscrollview

I'm looking for a way to draw a fade effect on a table view (and outline view, but I think it will be the same) when the content is scrolled. Here is an example from the [Fantastical](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fantastical/id435003921?mt=12) app:

[image: fade effect on top]

Also a video of a similar fade on QuickLook windows [here](http://blip.tv/truppelito/fade-effect-on-nstableview-nsoutlineview-5840941).

---

To make this I tried subclassing the scrollview of a tableview with this code:

```
#define kFadeEffectHeight 15

@implementation FadingScrollView

- (void)drawRect: (NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect: dirtyRect];

    NSGradient* g = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor: [NSColor blackColor] endingColor: [NSColor clearColor]];

    NSRect topRect = self.bounds;
    topRect.origin.y = self.bounds.size.height - kFadeEffectHeight;
    topRect.size.height = kFadeEffectHeight;

    NSRect botRect = self.bounds;
    botRect.size.height = kFadeEffectHeight;

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setCompositingOperation: NSCompositeDestinationAtop];
    // Tried every compositing operation and none worked. Please specify wich one I should use if you do it this way

    [g drawInRect: topRect angle: 90];
    [g drawInRect: botRect angle: 270];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

...but this didn't fade anything, probably because this is called before the actual table view is drawn. I have no idea on how to do this :(

By the way, both the tableview and the outlineview I want to have this effect are view-based, and the app is 10.7 only.

Comment: can you provide a video of the effect or the iTunes link of the app you are inspiring on?

Comment: @viggio24 added the link to Fantastical on the app store and a video of another example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mac OS X (as your question is tagged), there are several gotchas that make this difficult. This especially true on Lion with elastic scrolling.

I've (just today) put together what I think is a better approach than working on the table or outline views directly: a custom NSScrollView subclass, which keeps two "fade views" tiled in the correct place atop its clip view. [JLNFadingScrollView](http://github.com/jnozzi/JLNFadingScrollView) can be configured with the desired fade height and color and is free/open source on Github. Please respect the license and enjoy. :-)

[image: Examples of JLNFadingScrollView]